# Program doesn't print result of decryption

Tags: python, encryption

Hi guys my python code doesn't print anything after entering final input. Can you help? Many thanks :).

Code:

```
import getpass
import random                                                                                                                               #imports random module
import codecs                                                                                                                               #imports codecs module for encode task (UTF8)
import time

w = getpass.getpass("Input the Password: ") 
with open('Password.txt') as f:
    found = False
    for line in f:
        if w in line:

            Decrypted_Phrase = input("Please enter the phrase that you would like to decrypt: ")
            Number_Shift = input("Please enter the number the phrase was shifted by: ")

            Decryption_Base = ["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,./;:<>?'@#~]}[{=+-_)(*&^%$£!`¬\|"]
            Cipher = input("Please enter the keyword cipher to decrypt the phrase by: ")
            for c in Cipher:
                if c in Decryption_Base:
                    Actual_Cipher = Decryption_Base[(Decryption_Base.index(c)-Number_Shift)/(len(Decryption_Base))]
                    print (Actual_Cipher)
```

I have imported time, codecs and random for future additions to code.

EDIT:

Here is what the code outputs:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\getpass.py", line 101
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Input the Password: Rah
Please enter the phrase that you would like to decrypt: n
Please enter the number the phrase was shifted by: ]YY
Please enter the keyword cipher to decrypt the phrase by: 44
```

Comment: What type of input are you entering? You can stick some print statements in your code to see what `if` branches are not executed.

Comment: Where do your code drives You? Do You see any prints after `Input the Password:`?

Comment: I believe you want to have `%` instead of `/` in the `Decrypton_Base[...]`

Comment: Here you go guys :).

Comment: I tried that @kameranis

Comment: If anyone could help that would be great, cheers for suggested issues so far :).

Comment: Try replacing all `input` with `raw_input` typecasting where necessary

Comment: As the number the phrase was shifted by, you input ]YY. That's not a number.

Comment: Thank you @Ukimiku I shall test that

Comment: Still nothing, that's not the issue.

Comment: Is your program supposed to do a Caesar's chiffre?

Comment: My encryption program encrypts the message by encrypting a keyword with a Caesar cipher and then encrypts the phrase with the encrypted keyword.

Comment: Would you mind uploading your password.txt file? I can't execute your code without it.

Comment: Decryption_Base is a list containing a single string. I suspect it should just be the string?

Comment: You should be aware that if `w` is an empty string, `w in line` will *always* be true. Your password protection is therefore useless. (When fixing this, also bear in mind that `line` probably ends with a newline character.)

Comment: password.txt is simply Rah in a file saved as Password.txt

Comment: thank you @squeamishossifrage

Comment: And yes thats true @TomDalton

Comment: @squeamishossifrage thats not the case, it works.

Comment: Please help, I am still stuck

Comment: Still no luck from my end